# Save Async Task result

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know not much about Async Task so I'm sorry if my question is so basic.
I have a AsyncTask class which downloads some data from my database and show them in a listview..
Now my Fragment that contains my executing task will show Loading progress every time my Fragment restarts and this is a little annoying ..
                                                                                               So I decided to do this :

Download task begin in my Fragment(in setUserVisibleHint method), save result, and show them in my listview from there..
And repeat this every time app restarts..
But I have no idea how to do it , I would be so grateful if you could give me just a hint..

This is my **AsyncTask** class :

```
    public class RingBankAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private AsyncResponse delegate;
    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private String loadingMessage = "Loading...";
    private boolean showLoadingMessage = true;

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.context = context;
   }

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, boolean showLoadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.context = context;
     this.showLoadingMessage = showLoadingMessage;
   }

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.delegate = delegate;
  }

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, boolean showLoadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.showLoadingMessage = showLoadingMessage;
   }

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, String loadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.context = context;
     this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
     this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   public RingBankAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, String loadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate) {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
     this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
     if (this.showLoadingMessage == true) {
       this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
       this.progressDialog.setMessage(this.loadingMessage);
       this.progressDialog.show();
     }

     super.onPreExecute();
   }

   protected String doInBackground(String[] urls) {
     String result = "";

     for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
       result = invokePost(urls[i], this.postData);
     }

     return result;
   }

   private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
     String response = "";
     try {
       URL url = new URL(requestURL);

       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
       conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setDoInput(true);
       conn.setDoOutput(true);

       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

       writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

       writer.flush();
       writer.close();
       os.close();
       int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

       if (responseCode == 200) {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
           response = new StringBuilder().append(response).append(line).toString();
       }
       else {
         response = "";

         Log.i("RingBankAsyncTask", new StringBuilder().append(responseCode).append("").toString());
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return response;
   }

   private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     boolean first = true;

     for (Map.Entry entry : params.entrySet()) {
       if (first)
         first = false;
       else {
         result.append("&");
       }
       result.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
       result.append("=");
       result.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
     }

     return result.toString();
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     if ((this.showLoadingMessage == true) && 
       (this.progressDialog.isShowing())) {
       this.progressDialog.dismiss();
     }

     result = result.trim();

     this.delegate.processFinish(result);
   }

   public String getLoadingMessage() {
     return this.loadingMessage;
  }

   public void setLoadingMessage(String loadingMessage) {
    this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
   } 
   public HashMap<String, String> getPostData() {
     return this.postData;
   }
   public void setPostData(HashMap<String, String> postData) {
    this.postData = postData;
  }

   public Context getContext() {
     return this.context;
   }

   public AsyncResponse getDelegate() {
     return this.delegate;
   }
 }
```

And I call it like this :

```
    RingBankAsyncTask task = new RingBankAsyncTask(getActivity(), this);
    task.execute(myUrl);
```

Comment: you want to display data on  every 10 second or you want to display data first??

Comment: I want to display data when my Fragment is visible , and I don't want to execute my task everytime my Fragment restarts

Comment: By result do you mean your StringBuilder, or the outcome of this code ?

Comment: OK ITS POSSIBLE

Comment: @SanVed I mean outcome as you said

Comment: see my answer  only for 1 time asyncktask

Comment: The database you access is  remote database right??? Or just a local SQLite database?

Comment: @NishanKhadka  mySql

Comment: Then you can just save the result from async task in your local database and populate data in your listview from your local database. I think that will solve your problem. You can always check if your local database table is empty or not. If it is i.e. when the app is opened for the very first time, it will hit the api, next time onwards it will just fetch data from your local database and populate the ListView.

Comment: @NishanKhadka It seems like a good idea , I'll try it , thanks

Comment: If you need any help, I can help you with that :)

Comment: @NishanKhadka This is my project link , if you got some free time feel free to look into it and provide an answer for my question for benefit on me and others who come across this .. thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137724/discussion-between-nishan-khadka-and-mehran).

Comment: http://symphonyrecords.ir/RingtoneApp.rar

Comment: save data offline and populate ui.

Comment: @keyur9779 yeah,  this is the main purpose, but  my problem is how to save them

Comment: @Mehran use Sqlitedb.

Answer (score 1):

You should check check whether app is opening for the first time ot not.

```
         SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =.getSharedPreferences("CHEKINGFIRST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    first= sharedpreferences12.getString("FIRST", "");
    if(!first.equal("second")){ 
  RingBankAsyncTask task = new RingBankAsyncTask(getActivity(), this);
task.execute(myUrl);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencess=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CHEKINGFIRST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferencess.edit();
                    editor1.putString("FIRST","second");
                    editor1.commit();

              }
```

Comment: get activity or context you have to deside where is your code

Comment: hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

when your app starts, just set some flag `false` by using `SharedPreferences`. and again calling first time `AsyncTask` make `SharedPreferences` `flag` to true, and check each time app starts whether `flag` is `false` or `true`. 
and one more thing you can do for more control on fragment, use `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onActivityCreated` of your fragment, this will help you to retain fragment instance while changing `fragment` configuration.